# Где искать файл с текстом письма?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Здравствуйте.
В окружении `development` установил `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file` - при отправке письма не отправлять его, а записывать в файл.
Вопрос: где искать это файл? В какой файл будет записан текст письма?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# output to tmp/mails directory
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file
# ... and to specify output location
config.action_mailer.file_settings = { :location => Rails.root.join('tmp/mail') }
```

Comment: Спасибо. По умолчанию, кстати, письма пишутся в лог.